# UFT error while running SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, automated-tests, qtp

I need the query to run in UFT 12.51. `FileDate` is a variable for date format like `"2017-03-30"`. When I manually run this query in the SQL Management Studio, it gives me the correct result as follows:

```
present     |Amount     |Outgoing                 |OAmount    |Variance
============+===========+=========================+===========+========
1st Present |5028510.18 |Sales                    |5110968.89
------------+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+--------
1P 1-Sided  |0.00       |Cash Advances            |0.00       |0.00
------------+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+--------
            |NULL       |Returns                  |-82458.71  |
------------+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+--------
Total       |5028510.18 |Outgoing Settlement Total|5028510.18 |0.00
```

For UFT, I run it with regular `execute` command:

```
objRecordSet = objConnection.Execute(query)
```

But when running from UFT, it has the error message:

> Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>
> Function file: *(path)*
>   Line (50): "Set objRecordSet = objConnection.Execute(query)"

I tried to run the query without 'GO', with them carried to new line (adding to the query pieaces like `"&VBNewLine&" GO "&VBNewLine&"` as well as `"&ChrW(13)&ChrW(10)&"`istead of `VBNewLIne` - it gives the same error message. Any idea what that can be caused by?

The query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TempTableOutgoing, TempTableOutgoingLeft, TempTableOutgoingRight
GO
SELECT Table1.RowNum, Table1.present, Table2.Amount INTO TempTableOutgoingLeft FROM
    (Select cte.* FROM (VALUES ('1','1st Present'), ('2','1P 1-Sided'), ('3','')
    ) as cte (RowNum,present)) AS Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ca.* FROM [TRANS_DISTRIB] AS t1
      CROSS APPLY (Values
        ('1',  CONVERT(VARCHAR, FirstPresent)),
        ('2',  CONVERT(VARCHAR, FirstPresentOneSided)),
        ('3',NULL)
        ) AS ca (RowNum, Amount)
    WHERE t1.FileDate = ''"&FileDate&"'' AND t1.CardType = 'AMEX') as Table2
    on Table1.RowNum = Table2.RowNum
GO
SELECT * INTO TempTableOutgoingRight FROM(
SELECT vi.rownumber, vi.outgoing, vi.oamount FROM [eBalance].[dbo].[AMEX_OUTGOING] AS V1
      CROSS APPLY (Values ('1','Sales', Sales),
                    ('2','Cash Advances', CashAdvances),
                    ('3','Returns', Credits)
            ) as vi (rownumber, outgoing, oamount)
WHERE v1.FileDate = ''"&FileDate&"'')R
GO
SELECT RowNum, Present, Amount, Outgoing, OAmount INTO TempTableOutgoing FROM(
SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM TempTableOutgoingLeft
UNION ALL
SELECT '4','Total',  CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(CAST(ISNULL(Amount,'0') AS decimal(15,2)))) from TempTableOutgoingLeft) AS Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM TempTableOutgoingRight
UNION ALL
SELECT '4','Outgoing Settlement Total',  CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(CAST(ISNULL(oamount,'0') AS decimal(15,2)))) from TempTableOutgoingRight) AS Table2
ON Table1.RowNum = Table2.rownumber) Z
GO 
DROP TABLE TempTableOutgoingLeft
DROP TABLE TempTableOutgoingRight
GO
SELECT present, Amount, Outgoing, OAmount, Variance FROM(
SELECT * FROM dbo.TempTableOutgoing z1
INNER JOIN (Select RowN, Variance from (
SELECT DISTINCT RowN, Variance FROM TempTableOutgoing AS TTO
     CROSS APPLY (Values 
        ('1',''),('2', (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(CAST(ISNULL(Amount,'0') AS decimal(15,2)))-SUM(CAST(ISNULL(OAmount,'0') AS decimal(15,2))))
        FROM TempTableOutgoing where RowNum IN (1,2,3))), ('3','')) 
        as z (RowN,Variance)    where TTO.RowNum IN (1,2,3)
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT z.* FROM TempTableOutgoing AS TTO
     CROSS APPLY (Values 
        ('4', (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(CAST(ISNULL(Amount,'0') AS decimal(15,2)))-SUM(CAST(ISNULL(OAmount,'0') AS decimal(15,2))))
        FROM TempTableOutgoing where RowNum IN (4)))
        ) as z (RowN,Variance)  where TTO.RowNum IN (4)
) V Group by RowN, Variance) V1
on z1.RowNum = V1.RowN) T
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`GO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go) is batch separator for `SSMS` and sqlcmd. I propose to simply omit it and end each statement with `;`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TempTableOutgoing, TempTableOutgoingLeft, TempTableOutgoingRight;

SELECT Table1.RowNum, Table1.present, Table2.Amount INTO TempTableOutgoingLeft FROM
    (Select cte.* FROM (VALUES ('1','1st Present'), ('2','1P 1-Sided'), ('3','')
    ) as cte (RowNum,present)) AS Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ca.* FROM [eBalance].[dbo].[TRANS_DISTRIB] AS t1
      CROSS APPLY (Values
        ('1',  CONVERT(VARCHAR, FirstPresent)),
        ('2',  CONVERT(VARCHAR, FirstPresentOneSided)),
        ('3',NULL)
        ) AS ca (RowNum, Amount)
    WHERE t1.FileDate = ''"&FileDate&"'' AND t1.CardType = 'AMEX') as Table2
    on Table1.RowNum = Table2.RowNum;

SELECT * INTO TempTableOutgoingRight FROM(
SELECT vi.rownumber, vi.outgoing, vi.oamount FROM [eBalance].[dbo].[AMEX_OUTGOING] AS V1
      CROSS APPLY (Values ('1','Sales', Sales),
                    ('2','Cash Advances', CashAdvances),
                    ('3','Returns', Credits)
            ) as vi (rownumber, outgoing, oamount)
WHERE v1.FileDate = ''"&FileDate&"'')R;

SELECT RowNum, Present, Amount, Outgoing, OAmount INTO TempTableOutgoing FROM(
SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM TempTableOutgoingLeft
UNION ALL
SELECT '4','Total',  CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(CAST(ISNULL(Amount,'0') AS decimal(15,2)))) from TempTableOutgoingLeft) AS Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM TempTableOutgoingRight
UNION ALL
SELECT '4','Outgoing Settlement Total',  CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(CAST(ISNULL(oamount,'0') AS decimal(15,2)))) from TempTableOutgoingRight) AS Table2
ON Table1.RowNum = Table2.rownumber) Z;

DROP TABLE TempTableOutgoingLeft;
DROP TABLE TempTableOutgoingRight;

SELECT present, Amount, Outgoing, OAmount, Variance FROM(
SELECT * FROM dbo.TempTableOutgoing z1
INNER JOIN (Select RowN, Variance from (
SELECT DISTINCT RowN, Variance FROM TempTableOutgoing AS TTO
     CROSS APPLY (Values 
        ('1',''),('2', (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(CAST(ISNULL(Amount,'0') AS decimal(15,2)))-SUM(CAST(ISNULL(OAmount,'0') AS decimal(15,2))))
        FROM TempTableOutgoing where RowNum IN (1,2,3))), ('3','')) 
        as z (RowN,Variance)    where TTO.RowNum IN (1,2,3)
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT z.* FROM TempTableOutgoing AS TTO
     CROSS APPLY (Values 
        ('4', (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(CAST(ISNULL(Amount,'0') AS decimal(15,2)))-SUM(CAST(ISNULL(OAmount,'0') AS decimal(15,2))))
        FROM TempTableOutgoing where RowNum IN (4)))
        ) as z (RowN,Variance)  where TTO.RowNum IN (4)
) V Group by RowN, Variance) V1
on z1.RowNum = V1.RowN) T;

--DROP TABLE TempTableOutgoing
```

---

Also it looks like you are concatenating your SQL String:

```
 WHERE v1.FileDate = ''"&FileDate&"'')R
```

It could lead to SQL Injection attacks. Consider using parameter binding instead.